# adonisjs migration issue with mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, adonis.js

I'm trying to get the hang of adonisjs through [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-web-app-with-adonisjs)

I set up everything properly as instructed in there but I run into a problem when I type `adonis migration:run`. 
The error I get on Terminal is `Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I have 0 experience with mysql and this confuses me. I'd appreciate some guidance/help here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

@katotopark, this means your MySQL server is rejecting the connection from the Adonisjs application. check for a file called (.env) in the root folder of your project and inside you will need to add the credentials for the connection the MySQL server. (probably **user**: root, **password**: the password you use when you installed MySQL)

your .env should look similar to this.

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_USER=root/or-another-mysql-user
DB_PASSWORD=your-database-user-password***
DB_DATABASE=the_name_of_your_database
```

Regards.